# Harddrive showing in hwinfo, lsusb, but not lsblk or gparted

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, gparted

So, I wrote zeros to an external harddrive:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

But now, my external harddrive doesn't show in lsblk or gparted.

dmesg:

```
[ 2307.494165] usb 3-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 2307.514741] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10a8
[ 2307.514744] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2307.514746] usb 3-3: Product: Elements 10A8
[ 2307.514747] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 2307.514749] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 575838314537334858444635
[ 2307.516140] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2307.516251] scsi host4: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[ 2308.526738] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 10A8    1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2308.527080] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2308.528229] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 2309.550193] .
[ 2310.574113] .
[ 2311.598181] .
[ 2312.622168] .
[ 2313.646166] .
[ 2314.670156] .
[ 2315.694153] .
[ 2316.718141] .
[ 2317.742129] .
[ 2318.766096] .
[ 2318.766879] ready
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1058:10a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Portable (WDBUZG)
```

hwinfo:

```
20: USB 00.0: 10600 Disk
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: CiZ2.XMrwKxiZes9
  Parent ID: uIhY.xYNhIwdOaa6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-3:1.0
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "Western Digital Elements Portable (WDBUZG)"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1058 "Western Digital Technologies, Inc."
  Device: usb 0x10a8 "Elements Portable (WDBUZG)"
  Revision: "10.42"
  Serial ID: "575838314537334858444635"
  Driver: "usb-storage"
  Driver Modules: "usb_storage"
  Module Alias: "usb:v1058p10A8d1042dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uas is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uas"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: usb_storage is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe usb_storage"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #23 (Hub)
```

Any ideas what could be the cause, or how to fix, or if it's just perma-bricked?

Answer (score 1):

By writing zeros to the entire disk, you've overwritten the disk's partition table, so it doesn't look like a partitioned disc to the system.

You can recreate a partition table (GPT or MBR) with `gparted`, then partition the disk as you wish.

Comment: How can I create a partition if the disk doesn't show in gparted?

Comment: Start here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=zeroed+disk+recreate+MBR